# 204 No Content response, but dev-tools shows Content Download

Tags: http, google-chrome-devtools

I'm kind of novice to REST and HTTP subjects.
I was analising a website's performance (i didn't write the website), and looked into dev tools Networking tab.

Found out that a specific request was taking more than 9s to be completed.

**Here are the request headers:**

```
 POST /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
 Host: dummy.host.com
 ...
```

**The response headers**

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
```

---

### Here is a screenshot of the Timing Tab

- Why there is such a high `Content Download` time when the response
  was `204 No Content`?
- Is it the time the POST request took to be completed?

[image: Networking tab -> Request's Timing Tab]